# Getting error while making drawer layout using custom list

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I am getting error while creating left drawer in custom list. I am getting error where `inflater` inflate in `siliderAdapter.java`.

**Food Activity Class**

```
public class Food extends ActionBarActivity {
    ImageView licon;
    ImageView menu_btn;
    Intent i;
    Intent intent;
    ListView lv;
    String[] foodIcon;
    String[] FoodText;
    String [] food_id;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String[] userdata;
    public HashMap<String, String> catagories = new HashMap<String, String>();

    ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> mNavItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    String[] menu;
    DrawerLayout dLayout;
    ListView dList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food);



        licon=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.l_icon);
        menu_btn=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menu_btn);



        /*menu = new String[]{"Home","Android","Windows","Linux","Raspberry Pi","WordPress","Videos","Contact Us"};
        dLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        dList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menu);

        dList.setAdapter(adapter);
    //  dList.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);
*/

        String[]data={"History","Food","Location","Faranchise","Terms & Conditions","Log Out"};
        int[]icons={R.drawable.history,R.drawable.food,R.drawable.location,R.drawable.franchise,R.drawable.t_c,R.drawable.logout};

        //menu = new siliderAdapter(data,icons);
        dLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        dList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navlist);
        dList.setAdapter(new siliderAdapter(this,data,icons));
        dList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                /*dLayout.closeDrawers();                   
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("Menu", menu[position]);
                Fragment detail = new DetailFragment();
                detail.setArguments(args);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();         
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, detail).commit();*/

            }

        });

        i=new Intent(this,Location.class);
        intent=new Intent(this,SilideMenu.class);


        if(this.getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
        {

        Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();

        String msg=b.getString("msg");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         userdata=b.getStringArray("user_data");
//      if(userdata!=null){
//      user_data_bean ob = new user_data_bean();
//      
//
//      ob.set_User_id(userdata[0]);
//      ob.set_user_name(userdata[1]);
//      ob.set_email_id(userdata[2]);
//      ob.set_phone_number(userdata[3]);
//      ob.set_address(userdata[4]);
//      ob.set_status(userdata[5]);
//      ob.set_message(userdata[5]);
//      }
        }
        new getFoodCategory().execute();

        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.food_list);
        menu_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //startActivity(intent);
                drawer();
            }
        });

        licon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }// end of onCreate method

    public void drawer(){
        String[]data={"History","Food","Location","Faranchise","Terms & Conditions","Log Out"};
        int[]icons={R.drawable.history,R.drawable.food,R.drawable.location,R.drawable.franchise,R.drawable.t_c,R.drawable.logout};

        //menu = new siliderAdapter(data,icons);
        dLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        dList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        dList.setAdapter(new siliderAdapter(Food.this,data,icons));
       // adapter.setAdapter(new siliderAdapter(Food.this,data,icons));

     //   adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,(new siliderAdapter(data,icons)));

      //  dList.setAdapter(adapter);
    //  dList.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);

        dList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                /*dLayout.closeDrawers();                   
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("Menu", menu[position]);
                Fragment detail = new DetailFragment();
                detail.setArguments(args);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();         
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, detail).commit();*/

            }

        });
    }



    class getFoodCategory extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {


        @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
             super.onPreExecute();
             // Showing progress dialog
             pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Food.this);
             pDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
             pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
             pDialog.setCancelable(false);
             pDialog.show();

         }
         protected void onPostExecute(String []result) {
             super.onPostExecute(result);

                 lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(Food.this,FoodText,foodIcon,food_id,userdata));
                 pDialog.dismiss();
             }

        @Override
        protected String [] doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            JSONArray Food_Text = null;

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jCatagory = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            getFoods cat=new getFoods();
            String url="http://";
            String jsonStr = cat.viewRecords(url, getFoods.GET, null);
            //Log.d("Records", jsonStr);
            String FoodPath = null;
            if (jsonStr!= null) {

             try {
                 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                 Food_Text = jsonObj.getJSONArray("products");


                 for(int i=0; i<Food_Text.length();i++) {

                     JSONObject c = Food_Text.getJSONObject(i);
                     String foodId = c.getString("food_id");
                   //  Log.d("Cat Id", catId);
                     String food_name = c.getString("name");
                     JSONArray files = c.getJSONArray("files");

                     for(int k = 0; k<files.length();k++){
                         JSONObject filesPart = files.getJSONObject(k);
                          FoodPath = filesPart.getString("path");
                     }

                     catagories.put("path"+i,FoodPath);
                     catagories.put("cat_name"+i, food_name);
                     catagories.put("foodId"+i, foodId);

                   }

                 //System.out.println("catagories Size="+catagories.size());
                 FoodText = new String [catagories.size()/3];
                 foodIcon = new String [catagories.size()/3];
                 food_id = new String[catagories.size()/3];
             }

             catch (JSONException e) {
                 Log.d("catch", "in the catch");
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

            } else {
             Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
            }

             for(int k=0; k<catagories.size();k++){
              if(catagories.get("cat_name"+k)==null){
                //continue;  
              }else{
              FoodText[k]=catagories.get("cat_name"+k);
              foodIcon[k]=catagories.get("path"+k);
              food_id[k]=catagories.get("foodId"+k);
     //         jokesCates[k]=catagories.get("cat_name"+k);
                //System.out.print("cat_name"+catagories.get("cat_name"+k)+"\n");
                //System.out.print("Path"+catagories.get("path"+k)+"\n");
               } 
              }
            return null;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stubs

         } 
    }

}//end of class
```

**Silider adapter code goes here**

```
import student.briyani.CustomAdapter.holder;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class siliderAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    String [] text;
    int[] imgIcon;
    Context context;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    /*public siliderAdapter(Food food, String [] data, int [] icon){
        text=data;
        imgIcon=icon;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }*/
    public siliderAdapter(Food cat, String[] data, int[] icons) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        text=data;
        imgIcon=icons;
         context=cat;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return text.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public class holder{
         ImageView img;
         TextView txt;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final holder hldr=new holder();
        View rowView = null;
        //Bitmap bitmap = null;
          rowView = inflater.inflate(R.id.navlist, null);
          hldr.txt=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.siliderText);
          hldr.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);       
          hldr.txt.setText(text[position]);
          hldr.img.setImageResource(imgIcon[position]);
           rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*      String food_id=hldr.foodId.getText().toString();
                //Toast.makeText(context, "food_id="+food_id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Bundle b=new Bundle();
                b.putString("food_id", food_id);
                b.putStringArray("images", imgs);
                b.putStringArray("userData", userData);

                Intent Intent=new Intent(context, Menu.class);
                Intent.putExtras(b);
                context.startActivity(Intent);
        */  
    Toast.makeText(context, "Hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
        });
         return rowView;
    }

}
```

**Eror Message is**

```
> 10-26 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 10-26 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):
> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID
> #0x7f090050 type #0x12 is not valid 10-26 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2115)
> 10-26 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:857) 10-26
> 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394) 10-26
> 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 10-26
> 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at
> student.briyani.siliderAdapter.getView(siliderAdapter.java:68) 10-26
> 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at
> android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2033) 10-26
> 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at
> android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772) 10-26
> 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at
> android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672) 10-26
> 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at
> android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:732) 10-26
> 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at
> android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1625) 10-26
> 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at
> android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1863) 10-26
> 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at
> android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278) 10-26 11:40:07.633:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224) 10-26 11:40:07.633:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
> 10-26 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1617)
> 10-26 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1401) 10-26
> 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at
> android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278) 10-26 11:40:07.633:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224) 10-26 11:40:07.633:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:907)
> 10-26 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278) 10-26 11:40:07.633:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224) 10-26 11:40:07.633:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431) 10-26
> 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at
> android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278) 10-26 11:40:07.633:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224) 10-26 11:40:07.633:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
> 10-26 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
> 10-26 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399) 10-26
> 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at
> android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278) 10-26 11:40:07.633:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224) 10-26 11:40:07.633:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431) 10-26
> 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at
> android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278) 10-26 11:40:07.633:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224) 10-26 11:40:07.633:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
> 10-26 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
> 10-26 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399) 10-26
> 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at
> android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278) 10-26 11:40:07.633:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224) 10-26 11:40:07.633:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431) 10-26
> 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at
> android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278) 10-26 11:40:07.633:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224) 10-26 11:40:07.633:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1489)
> 10-26 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442) 10-26
> 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-26
> 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-26 11:40:07.633:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 10-26
> 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-26
> 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 10-26 11:40:07.633:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
> 10-26 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 10-26
> 11:40:07.633: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: hey is there any one who help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public siliderAdapter(Food cat, String[] data, int[] icons) {

    text = data;
    imgIcon = icons;
    context = cat;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

This line

```
context = cat;
```

You assign a **Food** variable (cat) to a variable of the type **Context** (context), which is a mistake.

Modify your constructor and pass Context as parameter.

```
public siliderAdapter(Context ctx, Food cat, String[] data, int[] icons) {

    text = data;
    imgIcon = icons;
    context = ctx;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```